# How to select longest consecutive positive streak rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, rdbms

I have a table called `rev`. It has only two columns. Id and revNumber.

Here is my mysql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86586e/1/0

```
id  revNumber
1     2
2     3
3     5
4    -3
5     1
6    -4
```

Here consecutive positive numbers are `2,3 and 5` and `1` so the longest streak is `2,3,5`
How can I select in mysql?

Thank you.

Comment: What should be the output? Just those 3 numbers?

Comment: Sorry I asked the wrong question, edited the question. Please see

Comment: What if there are multiple streaks with same length ?

Comment: Then the last one.

Comment: @ShakilAhmed what is your MySQL server version ? Can you upgrade to latest version (8+) ? This requires `LAG()` functionality

Comment: MySQL version is 5.7.23

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i can upgrade version. no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you commented that you can upgrade to MySQL 8.0, here is a solution that uses window functions. You can compute a cumulative sum and compare it to the row number in order to identify the streaks. Sorting can be used to identify the longest streak, like:

The following query will give you a unique record that represents the longest streak of positive numbers (count of records, list of ids and list of revision numbers).

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) cnt, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(rev_number ORDER BY id) rev_numbers
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        rev_number,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) rn,
        rev_number > 0 is_pos,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rev_number > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY id) sm
    FROM mytable
) x
GROUP BY (rn - sm), is_pos
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7XyvC1QqwtXSqNAjesRaTo/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| cnt | ids   | rev_numbers |
| --- | ----- | ----------- |
| 3   | 1,2,3 | 2,3,5       |
```